# Выравнивание. Верстка блока новостей

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо сделать так. Но у меня получается вот так.

```css
body {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

.block-name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #535353;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #c2c2c2;
}

.such-post {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  min-height: 310px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(217, 217, 217, 1);
}

.post {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  min-height: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(217, 217, 217, 1);
}

#search {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(217, 217, 217, 1);
}

input[type="search"] {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mini-post {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.mini-post>img {
  width: 27%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mini-post-name,
.mini-post-comment {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #717171;
  width: 72%;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="such-post">
          <p class="block-name">Resent Post</p>
          <div class="post-list">
            <div class="mini-post">
              <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/vnrhistory/images/e/e2/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BA.png/revision/latest?cb=20151015201730&path-prefix=ru" alt="0">
              <a href="" class="mini-post-name">Curabitur bibendum tortor in diam viverra</a>
              <p class="mini-post-comment">2 comments</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mini-post">
              <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/vnrhistory/images/e/e2/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BA.png/revision/latest?cb=20151015201730&path-prefix=ru" alt="0">
              <a href="" class="mini-post-name">Curabitur bibendum tortor in diam viverra</a>
              <p class="mini-post-comment">2 comments</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mini-post">
              <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/vnrhistory/images/e/e2/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BA.png/revision/latest?cb=20151015201730&path-prefix=ru" alt="0">
              <a href="" class="mini-post-name">Curabitur bibendum tortor in diam viverra</a>
              <p class="mini-post-comment">2 comments</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="post">
          <p class="block-name">Class aptent tacitı sociosu ad litora </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div id="search">
          <p class="block-name">Search</p>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Как правильно сделать что-то вроде этого?**

Comment: А что вы хотите получить?! У вас название статьи идет в инлайн элементе, а комменты в блочном. Если вы html оставите таким же, то ссылке назначайте display: block; и остальные аттрибуты. img - float: left; и уберите дисплей, а комменты также добавляйте блоком. Тогда строки будут друг под другом а изображение слева

Comment: или оберните ссылку в блочный элемент - div или p, а картинке назначьте свойство float: left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задала `.mini-post>img { float: left; }` и `.mini-post { overflow: hidden; }`:

```css
body {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

.block-name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #535353;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #c2c2c2;
}

.such-post {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  min-height: 310px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(217, 217, 217, 1);
}

.post {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  min-height: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(217, 217, 217, 1);
}

#search {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(217, 217, 217, 1);
}

input[type="search"] {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mini-post {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mini-post>img {
  width: 27%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.mini-post-name,
.mini-post-comment {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #717171;
  width: 72%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="such-post">
          <p class="block-name">Resent Post</p>
          <div class="post-list">
            <div class="mini-post">
              <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/vnrhistory/images/e/e2/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BA.png/revision/latest?cb=20151015201730&path-prefix=ru" alt="0">
              <a href="" class="mini-post-name">Curabitur bibendum tortor in diam viverra</a>
              <p class="mini-post-comment">2 comments</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mini-post">
              <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/vnrhistory/images/e/e2/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BA.png/revision/latest?cb=20151015201730&path-prefix=ru" alt="0">
              <a href="" class="mini-post-name">Curabitur bibendum tortor in diam viverra</a>
              <p class="mini-post-comment">2 comments</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mini-post">
              <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/vnrhistory/images/e/e2/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BA.png/revision/latest?cb=20151015201730&path-prefix=ru" alt="0">
              <a href="" class="mini-post-name">Curabitur bibendum tortor in diam viverra</a>
              <p class="mini-post-comment">2 comments</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="post">
          <p class="block-name">Class aptent tacitı sociosu ad litora </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div id="search">
          <p class="block-name">Search</p>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Но на девайсах с разрешением больше `960px` отображается не очень корректно.

Comment: @Cactus, что именно не корректно ? http://prntscr.com/equfp5

Comment: например отступ слева есть только в первом рядке названия поста. И количество комментариев должно было бы быть с новой строчки :)

Comment: @Cactus, ну с комментариями поправила, обновила ответ. А вот отступы уже сами расставите. Я не вижу у первого отличия в отступах от остальных пунктов.

Comment: то, что надо. Спасибо)